# How do you enable the horizontal scroll in in a vc++ clistbox?

Tags: visual-c++, scrollbar

How do you enable the horizontal scroll in in a vc++ clistbox?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listbox/article.php/c4759